# How change docker log length limit to more than 16k

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, grafana-loki, promtail

I am running docker swarm on engine version `20.10.17`. I find out, some application making long logs (more than 16k) and in Loki, as my logging stack, I cannot parse JSON logs, because docker split logs by 16k strings and insert date in the middle of the log message.

I implement python script, that generates string based on string length and this is my findings (I'll replace repeating character to make it readable).

I message length is `16383`:

```
2022-12-09T11:11:45.750162015Z xxxxxxxxx........xxxxx
```

I message length is `16384` - this is the limit:

```
2022-12-09T11:13:15.903855127Z xxxxxxxxx........xxxxx2022-12-09T11:13:15.903855127Z
```

- the date `2022-12-09T11:13:15.903855127Z` is the same at the beginning and at the end of message.

I message length is `16385`:

```
2022-12-09T11:14:46.061048967Z xxxxxxxxx........xxxxx2022-12-09T11:14:46.061048967Z x
```

This is my configuration of docker daemon:

```json
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "5m",
    "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

Is there a way how to change the configuration of length of log line? From docs I did not find this option and from [source code](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/logger/copier.go#L21) it looks like its hardcoded. What is the best way how to parse logs properly?

In Loki, I can see whole log as one peace of log, but with dates (e.g. `2022-12-09T11:19:56.575690222Z` ) in the middle of the log file (multiple times, based on the length of log line). This is quiet complicated way how to solve it, because that means, I have to check every log processed by Promtail.